# Unit testing bidirectional converters

Tags: java, unit-testing

While writing unit tests for a bidirectional converter, I was wondering whether it would be enough to cover only one direction with a unit test. Assume a converter that converts both from `a -> b` and from `b -> a`:

```
class Converter<A, B> {
    B convertToB(A a) { /* ... */ }
    A convertToA(B b) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Or more formally:

```
f(a) = b
f(b) = a
```

Standard unit tests would have to test both conversion directions. It's however very easy to write tests like `f(f(a)) == a`. Let's assume, `f(a) == b` is covered by a unit test. Which of these tests would be necessary and 
sufficient to cover `f(b) == a`?

```
(1) f(f(a)) == a
(2) f(f(b)) == b
(3) f(f(a)) == a && f(f(b)) == b
```

or do we have to test

```
(4) f(b) == a
```

Comment: Theoretically it will be sufficient to test that `f(f(a)) == a` if `f(a) == b` is given (by another unit test). But that's just the theory of mathematical equations.

Comment: I would test both the methods `converToA` and `convertToB` as they are two independent methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the view of the mathematical theory:

If `f(a) == b` is given you can say:

- `f(f(a)) == a` can be evaluated to `f(b) == a` and is therefore sufficient to test.
- `f(f(b)) == b` is not sufficient to test! That's because you don't prove that `f(b) == a`. If you just prove `f(f(b)) == b`, it might be given that `f(b) == b`!

Answer (score 1):

You're not covering error cases like `convertToB(null);`
And if you test `assertEquals(bObject, convertToB(convertToA(bObject)));` you'll never know where the eventual problem is.

I think you should test positive cases and some error or edge cases.

```
f(a) = b
f(b) = a
f(null) = ?
f(f(b)) = b
f(f(a)) = a
```

Depending on conversion rules (as I don't know how A and B are related) you should test even more cases (e.g. A object with foo property set to a value, A object with foo property set to null, ...).
You may take a look at [equivalence partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning) testing technique to derive minimum required test cases.

Comment: Additional edge case testing is indeed necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to test the f(a)==b as well.

An sample implementation of Converter:

```
Int convertToB(Int a) { return -a }
Int convertToA(Int b) { return -a }
```

would pass the f(f(a))==a tests. While it obviously does not work correctly ;)